# Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 -- fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory #include <zlib.h>

Tags: compiling, gcc, make, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zlib

I am relatively new to Ubuntu. I have set up a Ubuntu 18.04 subsystem on my Windows 10 PC for bioinformatics applications.

During multiple application installations, I have received the following error after running ./configure & make:

```
bgzf.h:33:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <zlib.h>
```

The configure command returns:

```
checking for ZLIB... yes
```

Whereis returns:

```
zlib: /usr/local/bin/zlib.h /usr/include/zlib.h /usr/share/man/man3/zlib.3.gz
```

echo | gcc -E -v - returns:

```
Reading specs from /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/specs
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/src/gcc/configure --build=x86_64-build_pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/gcc_built --with-sysroot=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/gcc_built/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --with-pkgversion='crosstool-NG 1.23.0.449-a04d0' --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libmudflap --enable-libgomp --disable-libssp --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libsanitizer --enable-libmpx --with-gmp=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/buildtools --with-mpfr=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/buildtools --with-mpc=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/buildtools --with-isl=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/buildtools --enable-lto --enable-threads=posix --enable-target-optspace --enable-plugin --enable-gold --disable-nls --disable-multilib --with-local-prefix=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/gcc_built/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot --enable-long-long --enable-default-pie
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (crosstool-NG 1.23.0.449-a04d0)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/cc1 -E -quiet -v -iprefix /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/ -isysroot /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/gcc_built/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include
 /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include-fixed
 /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/include
 /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include
End of search list.
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"
COMPILER_PATH=/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../libexec/gcc/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/../lib/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/../lib/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/lib/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

Other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148075/compilation-error-missing-zlib-h)  have suggested a zlib-dev installation, already have the latest zlib1g-dev,version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2).

Could you please advise on the best route to overcome this error? Thank you so much.

Output from echo | gcc -E -v -

```
Reading specs from /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6- 
linux-gnu/7.3.0/specs
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/src/gcc/configure --build=x86_64-build_pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/gcc_built --with-sysroot=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/gcc_built/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --with-pkgversion='crosstool-NG 1.23.0.449-a04d0' --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libmudflap --enable-libgomp --disable-libssp --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libsanitizer --enable-libmpx --with-gmp=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/buildtools --with-mpfr=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/buildtools --with-mpc=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/buildtools --with-isl=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/.build/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/buildtools --enable-lto --enable-threads=posix --enable-target-optspace --enable-plugin --enable-gold --disable-nls --disable-multilib --with-local-prefix=/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/gcc_built/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot --enable-long-long --enable-default-pie
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (crosstool-NG 1.23.0.449-a04d0)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/cc1 -E -quiet -v -iprefix /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/ -isysroot /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/home/rdonnelly/mc/conda-bld/compilers_linux-64_1534865402226/work/gcc_built/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include
 /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/include-fixed
 /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/include
 /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include
End of search list.
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"
COMPILER_PATH=/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../libexec/gcc/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/../lib/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/../lib/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/lib/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin/../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

Comment: Well, `gcc` would normally be able to find headers in `/usr/include` - unless it's configured differently for WSL? It might be helpful to [edit] your question to include the output of command `echo | gcc -E -v -` (or at least the section of it begining `#include "..." search starts here`)

Comment: @steeldriver --- sorry for the delay here, I've copied the output for echo | gcc -E -v -

Comment: So it looks like you have an anaconda3 toolchain that is taking over the build process (preventing the regular "system" toolchain from running). Unless that's intentional, I suggest you examine your `~/.bashrc` and (at least temporarily) comment out anaconda3 related stuff - or at least make sure /home/USER/anaconda3/bin/ is later in your `PATH` than the `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin` directories

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @steeldriver -- I commented out the anaconda section of ~/.bashrc  and tried re-running without any luck. I also did not see anaconda3 in my PATH (though it is in my home directory).

Comment: I've added anaconda3 to my PATH-- echo $PATH 

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/USER/anaconda3/bin: